# I am not able to use the function TrackerKCF from de library opencv

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\douglas\rastreamento.py", line 3, in <module>
    rastreador = cv2.TrackerKCF()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerKCF'
```

Thats the code, even if theres no need to see.

```
import cv2

rastreador = cv2.TrackerKCF() >

video = cv2.VideoCapture('race.mp4')
ok, frame = video.read()

bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame)
```

Does that mean the library isn't updated or something? By the way I'm using VS Code, and all the others functions called by `cv2` its colored green, but that one is in white.

Comment: You need to install opencv_contrib. Take a look at https://forum.opencv.org/t/tracker-not-found/4252

Answer (score 0):

`TrackerKCF_create()` is not in the regular opencv-python module.

You have to install [opencv-contrib-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/) by command `pip install opencv-contrib-python` to get it.